# Необычный редирект на PHP (или JS)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url, redirect

Есть проект. В нем много почти одинаковых страниц. Отличаются они только по порядковому номеру. Например:

```
http:// vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr1.php
http:// vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr2.php
...
http:// vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr300.php
```

На каждой странице есть формочка. И обработка каждой формы происходит в файле connect.php Там идет отправка на почту, и подключение к бд.
 Я хочу чтоб после того, как данные внеслись в бд был автопереход на след проект.

Т.е. если заполнили и отправили форму с страницы

```
http:// vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr1.php
```

то чтоб автоматом листало на

```
http:// vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr2.php
```

И такс каждым прохождением. 
Если отправят форму с

```
http:// vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr200.php
```

чтоб перелистывало на

```
http:// vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr201.php
```

Как я пытался сделать: (код ниже будет с файла connect.php . он написан в самом низу) 
`$H=getenv("HTTP_REFERER");` выводит ссылку на стр с которой пользователль перешел

`$res = settype($H, "integer");` берет цифру из строки

`$next=$res+1;` прибавляет еденицу  (почему-то подумал что каждый раз будет прибавлять при обращении, но нет)

`header("Location: http://vote.awards.org.ua/pr/pr".$next.".php");` автопереброс на след проект по ссылке

Comment: Вы как узнаете, в какой проект нужно сохранить текущие данные? Берите от туда номер проекта, а не из `HTTP_REFERER`, в котором хранится полный url, а не цифра проекта (а может вообще быть пустым, удаленным файрволлом или прокси).

Answer (score 1):

Использовать getenv("HTTP_REFERER"), в вашем случае, не очень правильно. Многое зависит и от сервера и от браузера, да и работает HTTP_REFERER при переходе по ссылке. Вставляйте в форму скрытый инпут с текущим номером и на его основе делайте перенаправление.

Comment: Спасбо, так и сделал. Но чисто теоритически, возможно ли сделать без лишних  инпутов, в одном файле